# Why the overlay div cannot take the parent's dimensions

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button.
When the the mouse hovers the wrapper div (ks-wrapper), another div (ks-overlay) (that at the start is hidden) will be appeared and the based div (ks-button) hides. 
Its also necessary the button not have fixed dimensions.

Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div class="ks-wrapper">
  <div class="ks-button">
    <div class="ks-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="ks-content">
Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ks-overlay">
    "K"
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.ks-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ks-button {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.ks-header{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
  max-height:20px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
}

.ks-content{
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:grey;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
  height:100%;
}

.ks-wrapper .ks-overlay {
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: green;
  width: 97.5%;
  height: 85px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.ks-wrapper:hover .ks-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

**UPDATE**
For start I want to thank you all for your fast responses to my issue.
Secondly, I would like to make myself more clear... and also to add a couple of problems that I figure them out...

1)This button its gonna used in a responsive template. 
Is it possible the button not to have a fixed height, and the overlay to follow this height?

2)how can accomplish to have transition and to mouse leave (transition works only in hover)??

3)This button stays on top of the following elements

This is the [link in the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/PanosK/yzo9dhft/) that represents the issues.

Thank you a lot for your time

Comment: I used you example code and paste it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f9td7v5b/), what is different from your code to your need?

Answer (score 0):

the header is taking 20 px on the top.. you need tho add these to your `.ks-wrapper .ks-overlay {`

```css
.ks-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ks-button {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.ks-header{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
  max-height:20px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
}

.ks-content{
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:grey;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
  height:100%;
}

.ks-wrapper .ks-overlay {
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: green;
  width: 97.5%;
  height: 105px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.ks-wrapper:hover .ks-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ks-wrapper">
  <div class="ks-button">
    <div class="ks-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="ks-content">
Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ks-overlay">
    "K"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Serge. My problem is that I want not to do the sum. I want to be the height to adjust responsively according to the size of the text. The fixed height was only as example

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are saying about `.ks-overlay` which `overflow browser width` after certain screen `size`, if so then that's because of `padding` added in that, use `css box-sizing` property as below,

> The box-sizing property is used to alter the default CSS box model
>   used to calculate width and height of the elements.

```css
.ks-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 85px;
  width: 100%;
}
.ks-button {
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.ks-header{
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:yellow;
  max-height:20px;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
}

.ks-content{
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  background-color:grey;
  font-size:20px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-align:center;
  color:black;
  padding:5px;
  height:100%;
}

.ks-wrapper > .ks-overlay {
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  position: absolute;
  color: yellow;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 85px;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding:10px;
  overflow:hidden;
  left:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.ks-wrapper:hover .ks-overlay {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="ks-wrapper">
  <div class="ks-button">
    <div class="ks-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="ks-content">
Text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="ks-overlay">
    "K"
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you frnt! My problem didn't solved. I update my desciption and also I create a jsfiddle for showing the issues.